# Cakephp3 Custom ExceptionRenderer

Tags: php, exception, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to build a custom exception renderer for error 404. I modified my configuration has follows:

*app.php*

```
'Error' => [
        'errorLevel' => E_ALL,
        'exceptionRenderer' => 'App\Error\AppExceptionRenderer', // use my custom renderer
        'skipLog' => [],
        'log' => true,
        'trace' => true,
    ],
```

and created the following script:

*src/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php*

```
<?php
namespace App\Error;

use App\Controller\SiteHomepageController;
use Cake\View\View;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer as ExceptionRenderer;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException as Exception;

class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

  protected function _getController(){
    $controller = new SiteHomepageController(null,null,null);
    return $this->controller=$controller;
  }

  public function _template(Exception $exception, $method, $code)
  {
    $template = 'error';
    return $this->template = $template;
  }

  public function render(){

    $exception = $this->error;
    $code = $this->_code($exception);
    $method = $this->_method($exception);
    $template = $this->_template($exception, $method, $code);

    $this->controller->public=true;
    $this->controller->viewBuilder()->layout('site');
    $this->controller->viewBuilder()->templatePath('SiteHomepage');
    $this->controller->set('sez','');
    $this->controller->initialize();
    $this->controller->render($template);

    $event = new Event('');
    $this->controller->afterFilter($event);

    $this->controller->response->statusCode($code);

    return $this->controller->response;

  }

}
```

But I get the following error:

Strict (2048): Declaration of **App\Error\AppExceptionRenderer::_template()** should be compatible with **Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer::_template(Exception $exception, $method, $code)** [APP/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php, line 10]

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong and how to solve the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

in *src/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php*

**I replaced:**

```
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException as Exception;
```

**with:**

```
use Exception;
```

And it works!